# FieldArray fields.push({ no, id }) - no property can display but id property can't

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I use `fields.push({ no: idx + 1, id: item.name })`

### Code

XxxAddOrEditForm.js

```js
  <Form>
   .
   .
    <FieldArray>
       name="availableShops"
       component={MultiSelectFields}
       items={availableShops}
       preItems={xxxShops}
    </FieldArray>
   .
   .
  </Form>
```

MultiSelectFields.js

```js
const MultiSelectFields = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    await displaySelectedFields()
    prepareAvailableOptions()
  }, [])

  const prepareAvailableOptions = () => {
    setCurrentOptions(items)
    if (props.preItems.length > 0) {
      props.preItems.forEach(preItem => items.push(preItem))
    }
    setOriginalOptions(items)
  }

  const displaySelectedFields = () => {
    props.preItems.map((item, idx) => {
      fields.push({ no: idx + 1, id: item.name })
    })
  }
   .
   .
   .
  return (
    <>
     .
     .
      {fields.map((field, idx) => (
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <Field 
              name={`${field}.no`} 
              label="No."
              component={InputField}
              disabled
            />
          </Col>
          <Col span={2}>
            <Field
              name={`${field}.id`}
              label="Name"
              component={SelectField}
              input={{ onChange: selectShop(currentOptions) }}
              validate={[VALIDATION.required]}
              items={getAvailableFiltered(idx, currentOptions)}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Button>-</Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Row>
         .
         .
        </Row>
       .
       .
      }
     .
     .
    </>
  )
}
```

====

#### In UI...

No. field can display but Name field (Name is **id** in the code)
[image: GUI]

#### This is redux state

[image: Redux state]

id appear in redux state
Why id does not appear in the redux form (Name field), too?

Comment: I think it should be name={`${field.no}`} and  name={`${field.id}`} ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I see in a document... <Field name> props can input only String. https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/field.md

Comment: `${field.no}` and `${field.id}` will be string. With `${field}.no` instead you are trying to read the property `no` out the string `${field}` which is likely to return `undefined`